# How to use System.Timers.Timer properly inside a class

Tags: c#, system.timers.timer

I'm trying to learn how to use Timers and I'm having troubles with the elapsed event.
What I have is a class where I check some messages from a databatch. But now I want to make a timer where every x period of time check that messages.

I made this code:

```
public class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     Message m = new Message();
     m.init();
   }
}

public class Messages{

    private System.Timers.Timer tt;

    public void init()
    { 
       tt = new(_conf.Period);
       tt.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);
       tt.Start();
       Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      //Console.WriteLine for test it works
      Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
      //check my messages
    }

}
```

This doesn't work because it never goes inside TimerElapsed. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

EDIT: even as a field timer doesn't goes inside elapsed event.

EDIT2: well, I found my problem. I was testing the TimerElapsed with a Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow) inside of it and it only works if i put after all the code on Init a Console.ReadLine(); Ill edit my code again to show it. I don't understad why I need this readLine so if someone could explain to me would be great.

Comment: The code discards the timer instance, so it's garbage-collected before it has a chance to fire. Store it in a field instead of a variable

Comment: Still doesn't do anything even if I store it at class level :C

Comment: Well, the obvious follow up is to chain the same question - you're creating an instance of `Messages` and calling `init` on it - where are you storing a reference to *that* instance?

Comment: I have a Program class with Main method where I create my Message instance and call init

Comment: The fact that you "need" the `Console.ReadLine()` strongly suggests to me that this is a console app, you're calling `init` either directly or indirectly from the `Main` method and your program is running off the end of `Main` and so exiting before the timer fires. Please understand though that making people *guess* at what your code looks like isn't highly productive. Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: I edited with main class, I didn't think it was necessary because it just creates an instance of message and that's all. Sorry.l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like the `ReadLine()` approach, you can use a polling loop like this instead:

```
  public static void Main (string[] args) {     
    Messages m = new Messages();
    m.init();
    
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
    do {
      while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
      }
      cki = Console.ReadKey(true);  
    } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);    
  }
```

This will keep the app alive until the user hits the Escape key.

You should see the timestamps printing at whatever interval you specified.